# Зачем нужен контейнер std::map? В чем он обходит hash map?

Tags: c++, stl, map, хеширование

Зачем (в с++) существует контейнер map, если есть hash_map, который быстрее? Например, std::map  чем лучше std::unordered_map'a?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Нет понятия «лучше» или «хуже», есть различные свойства контейнера.

`std::map` держит данные в отсортированном по ключу виде, в отличие от `std::unordered_map`. Если вам нужно это свойство, вам нужен `std::map`. Если нет, достаточно и `std::unordered_map`.

(Как следствие отсортированности, например, в `std::map` есть функция [`lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound), которой нет в `std::unordered_map`.)

Comment: можно вопрос немного не по теме: поделитесь ссылкой как внутри устроены стандартные контейнеры?

Comment: @aleks.andr видео про stl контейнеры http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5jc9xFGsL8G3y3ywuFSvOuNm3GjBwdkb

Comment: @aleks.andr: Это не гарантировано стандартом, и каждый автор стандартной библиотеки может делать как ему вздумается, он лишь обязан соблюдать гарантии O-нотации (типа «добавление за O(1)»). Например, `std::map` в gcc сначала было AVL-деревом, а потом его перевели на красно-чёрное дерево. Так что никакого предписанного устройства контейнеров нету.

Comment: @VladD, благодарю за ссылку и разъяснение.

Answer (score 3):

Как видно из самого названия контейнера `std::unordered_map` элементы этого контейнера не упорядочены. В то время как элементы контейнера `std::map` упорядочены в соответствии с ключом.

Answer (score 0):

Для hash_map можно задать hash функцию.